# Coexistence of Intel AMT and AMD DASH in SCCM 2012 R2

Tags: intel, sccm, amd-processor

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Intel AMT **and** AMD DASH plug-ins in SCCM 2012 R2 to out of band manage clients?

I've successfully implemented the Intel AMT plug-in, now I'm wondering if I can also implement the AMD DASH plug-in on the same SCCM console. Someone got experience on this matter? I'd love to hear experiences and how-to's if something needs to be done.

I'm asking this because we've got a lot of Intels, but also AMDs. And we want to be able to manage both from the same platform.

Comment: [You cross-posted this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/735166/coexistence-of-intel-amt-and-amd-dash-in-sccm-2012-r2).  You should pick one and remove the other. [See the policy on cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).